# Unable to select a particular radio button choice by clicking on the choice text

Tags: html, css, jsf, seam, richfaces

```
<s:decorate template="/layout/display-text.xhtml">
    <h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" value="#{_userHome.pref}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{_userHome.getPreferences()}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</s:decorate>
```

I am able to select user preferences by directly clicking on the text next to the radio button choice in all browsers except Firefox. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a `<label>` element for the radio button so that your markup looks as follows:

```
<label for="radio-button">Radio button label text</label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="radio-button" id="radio-button"/>
```

The `for` and `id` attributes of the tags must match.  To create this label, you can use the [`<h:outputLabel/>`](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_11a) tag.