# Clicking the text to select corresponding radio button

Tags: html, css, forms, input, radio-button

I'm creating a quiz web application using PHP.  Each question is comprised of a separate `<label>` and has 4 possible choices, using `radio buttons` to allow the user to select his/her answer.  The current HTML for a single question looks like:

```
<label for="349">What is my middle name?</label>
<br>
<input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="349">Abe
<br>
<input id="349" type="radio" value="2" name="349">Andrew
<br>
<input id="349" type="radio" value="3" name="349">Andre
<br>
<input id="349" type="radio" value="4" name="349">Anderson
<br>
```

I would like the user to **have the option of clicking on the text associated with radio button.**  Right now, the user can only click on the radio button itself - which I find to be a quite cumbersome task.

I read [Unable to select a particular radio button choice by clicking on the choice text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396351/unable-to-select-a-particular-radio-button-choice-by-clicking-on-the-choice-text) and the suggestion points toward making the `for` and `id` attributes of the tags match.  I have done this and it still doesn't work.

My question is: **I'd like to be able to click the text of an `<input type="radio">` object, as opposed to only being able to select the radio button itself.**  I know I've read about this before but can't seem to find any solution to my problem.  Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Answer (score 190, accepted):

In your code, you've got a label on the form itself. You want to put labels on each individual radio group, as shown below.

```html
<form>
  <p>What is my middle name?</p>
  <br>
  <input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="question1">
  <label for="349">Abe</label>
  <br>
  <input id="350" type="radio" value="2" name="question1">
  <label for="350">Andrew</label>
  <br>
  <input id="351" type="radio" value="3" name="question1">
  <label for="351">Andre</label>
  <br>
  <input id="352" type="radio" value="4" name="question1">
  <label for="352">Anderson</label>
  <br>
</form>
```

You should keep in mind that two elements should never have the same ID. The `name` attribute is used so that the radio buttons function as a group and only allow a single selection at a time.

Comment: Excellently simple. Love it when an almost hidden feature of tags is re-discovered

Answer (score 44):

There seems to be a little unclickable space between the radio button and the label if done according to *Nathan*'s answer. Here is how to make them join seamlessly (see [this article](http://www.html.am/tags/html-label-tag.cfm)):

```
<form>
    <p>What is my middle name?</p>
    <br>
    <label><input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="question1">Abe</label>
    <br>
    <label><input id="350" type="radio" value="2" name="question1">Andrew</label>
    <br>
    <label><input id="351" type="radio" value="3" name="question1">Andre</label>
    <br>
    <label><input id="352" type="radio" value="4" name="question1">Anderson</label>
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: I prefer this answer. But are you sure you even need the "for" attributes with this approach?

Comment: @Piddu: I think you're right, so I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Another option to avoid the extra space between the radio button and label, is to simply not put it there `<input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="question1"><label for="349"> Abe</label>` (no spaces or newlines between the tags)

Comment: @AryeDovEidelman: Your solution does not work for Firefox, whereas mine does. =)

Comment: I just tested my way in chrome and firefox and found that it reduces the unclickable space from 7 to 3 pixels by removing the space character. see [why-is-there-an-unexplainable-gap-between-these-inline-block-div-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038799). the three remaining pixels are the default right margin on the radio button `margin: 3px 3px 0 5px;` (it's more noticeable in firefox as there is a hover effect by default) which can be fixed with CSS by removing the margin and replacing it with padding.

Comment: @AryeDovEidelman: I see, thanks for investigating! Though for simplicity I will stick to encasing the whole thing in the label. =)

Comment: please give me your email address or any other contact regarding https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37343/why-having-guru-is-must-to-advance-spiritually mine is alokmahor@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

The label tag should be around each answer, e.g. around Abe, Andrew, etc... and it needs to be unique for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing this for years, but neither of these work for me, using variables.

```
    echo "<input type='radio' name='student' id='$studentID' value='$studentID'>
        <label for='$studentID'>$fname</label> $lname<br />\n";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='student' id='$studentID' value='$studentID'>
        <label for='$studentID'>$fname $lname</label><br />\n";
```

and here is the source:

```
        <input type='radio' name='student' id='986875' value='986875'>
        <label for='986875'>John</label> Brown<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 <label for="1">hi</label>
 <input type="radio" id="1" />
```

So if you click on the text or label it selects the radio button.
But if you do this...

```
<label for="1">//</label>
```

and you add this to what the code I wrote just before this then if you click on the 2nd label then it will also select the radio.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting the input tag within the label tag ensures the label appears right next to the radio button. With the earlier approaches suggested, you can put the label tag anywhere within the html file and it will select the associated radio button when clicked. Check this out:

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <p>What is my middle name?</p>
  <br>
  <input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="question1">

  <br>
  <input id="350" type="radio" value="2" name="question1">
  <label for="350">Andrew</label>
  <br>
  <input id="351" type="radio" value="3" name="question1">

  <br>
  <input id="352" type="radio" value="4" name="question1">
  <label for="352">Anderson</label>
  <br>
</form><br/>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
  <label for="349">Abe</label><br/>
  <label for="351">Andre</label>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Doing it this way instead eliminates this flaw:

```html
<form>
  <p>What is my middle name?</p>
  <br>
  
  <label>
    <input id="349" type="radio" value="1" name="question1"/>Abe
  </label>
  <br>
  
  <label>
    <input id="350" type="radio" value="2" name="question1"/>Andrew
  </label>
  <br>
  
  <label>
    <input id="351" type="radio" value="3" name="question1"/>Andre
  </label>
  <br>
  
  <label>
    <input id="352" type="radio" value="4" name="question1"/>Anderson
  </label>
  <br>
</form>
```

Comment: I think the only point missing in your answer is that the reason that you can click on the label is because there is a 'for' attribute that links the input and the label together. Otherwise great answer.

Answer (score -2):

It's **NOT** a good idea to hard-code everything.

I'm using **Angular**.

For radio buttons or check boxes, you need to use **property binding**. Colors, for example:

In the .ts file:

```
colors = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo', 'Violet'];
```

In the .html file, the **"for" of the label** and the **"id" of the input** should have **the same value** as the singular variable on the right side of **ngFor** expression (here it's **"color"**), and **BOTH** the **"for"** and the **"id"** need to be put inside square brackets **[]**:

```
<div class="radio" *ngFor="let color of colors">
    <label [for]="color">
        <input type="radio" name="color" [id]="color" ngModel [value]="color">
        {{color}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Then you'll be able to select with the label.

Result:
[image]

Comment: The question was asked about PHP and HTML, so answers specific to angular are off-topic. The appropriate answer, to use basic HTML syntax to "for" and "id", is not hard coding, and adding hard-coded labels to radio button forms is the standard. It's an opinion whether hard-coded labels are appropriate, but that opinion is off topic to this question because regardless of hard-coding the labels provides a small, reproducible sample that answers the question in the shortest possible way without regards to for-loops.

Comment: No. It doesn't matter it's PHP, HTML, Angular, React, or Stencil, hard-code is never the first choice. I pointed out the flaw of the solutions above. If some people don't like it, so be it.