# HTML clickable radio button

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to select a radio button by clicking on text next to radio button. How can I enable click on radio button text to select radio button?

[What I tried is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj88a/)

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
```

Edit: 
I am sorry. I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863251/clicking-the-text-to-select-corresponding-radio-button)

Comment: A JS library which does this well http://www.onextrapixel.com/2014/01/07/label-your-input-fields-like-a-boss-with-label_better-js/

Answer (score 2):

You would use a `label` element and match the `for` attribute with the `id` of the `input`:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vyex9/)

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"/>
<label for="male">Male</label>

<input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"/>
<label for="female">Female</label>
```